# Unable to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7

Tags: 12.04, installation

I previously installed Ubuntu 12.10 using Wubi but it heated up my laptop too much and my battery ran out in minutes, so I removed it.

Now I am trying to do a **normal dual-boot install** using 12.04, but it wont go further than the boot screen. I am booting from a USB and when I reach the boot menu it gives a beeping sound. When I click "Install ubuntu" or any other option there is another beeping sound, but the process doesn't go any further.

My specs: Dell Vostro 3450 , Intel core i5 2410M, 4 GB RAM with AMD Graphics and Win7 64 bit professional pre-installed.

Comment: First [MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) the ISO you used to create the USB and recreate if necessary. Use [nomodeset](http://askubuntu.com/a/162076/14916) for your graphics card when you try to install.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check before installing Ubuntu along side windows 7 is your partition type. Because if it is *dynamic* then you can't install, so please check your partition type: 
just right click on *my computer* then select *manage* and then chose *disk management*. If the partition where your os is installed partition shows *dynamic* then convert it to *basic* and try to install Ubuntu again.